# Изменить колонтитул при печати

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Браузер автоматически добавляет в колонтитул содержимое тега h1 и добавляет дату. Можно как-то изменить его?

```
var printContents = $('#printContainer').html(); //скрывается в css print
$('#printContent').html(printContents) // отображается в css print
$('#printContent h1').text('Some text' + $('h1').text())

window.print(); // меняет h1 и все, а колонтитул не меняется
```

Comment: отключить печать колонтитулов в настройках печати в браузере не пробовали?

Comment: Мне нужно его изменить, а не удалить.